# UK standard visitor visa for job interview [Refusal]

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas

this is my first post and I would like to know what should I provide after getting my UK visitor visa refusal. [please help]

** This isn't the same question as here [link](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e) as i got refusal as i didn't meet the requirements for paragraphs V4.2 to V4.10

I have an interview and I am still a student. I have provided documents which show that I am a student and provided my parent's financial bank documents and also a document showing my savings in the bank despite the fact that the company sent me an invitation letter stating that they will take care of all of the financial aspects till I go back to my country. I also provided a traveling ticket and hotel reservations.

However i got the following decision : 
"With your visa application, other than an invitation letter, you have supplied no supporting documentation pertaining to your own financial circumstances in your country. As a result, I am unable to ascertain the veracity of the statements surrounding your financial circumstances or of any assets or savings you have , I am not satisfied that you have demonstrated sufficient ties to [my country] and the lack of supporting documentation submitted with your application casts doubt over your application as a whole. It is the intentions of the applicant that are paramount in considering any application and without this information and on the documentation before me on the balance of possibilities , I am therefore not satisfied that you intend to leave the UK at the end of your proposed visit or that you will not live in the UK for extended periods through frequent or successive visits. Furthermore, I am not satisfied that you are genuinely seeking entry for a purpose that is permitted by the visitor's routes and that you will not undertake any prohibited activities set out in V4.5 - V4.10 . Appendix V 4.2 - 4.10 "

What should I provide more to support my documents for the second time when applying to avoid getting my visa refusal again?

Answer (score 1):

> provided my parent's financial bank documents

Did you also provide an affidavit from your parents stating that they take all your financial responsibility?

You need to do that since I assume that your parents are responsible for your financial well-being and simply submitting their financial bank documents does not officially mean that you have rights/access to this money.

Comment: Well i had a sponsorship and just my parents were going to help me if i needed any money and send me .. that's why they gave me their bank statements and like i said its like an extra thing

Comment: I am no expert but I think the problem is that they think you do not have enough assets/money back in your home country in your name to return to after your visa stay has ended. So submitting your parents financial docs did not help your case at all. If you want to include their documents it needs to be accompanied by the affidavit.

Comment: Secondly never take visa rejections personally, there are thousands of shady applications each year so it just makes the embassies more careful.

Comment: Then what should i include ?

Comment: as i stated i also included my personal bank statement but i don't have alot in it , but i have savings in my account which i included too

Comment: *Unofficial advice: You could ask your parents to transfer a huge amount in your account temporarily*. I would suggest talk to an agent/expert in your home country who might be able to guide you better regarding your specific situation.

Comment: actually i did that before applying and my bank statement revealed that i have funds also besides some savings , but i got this response eventually :(

Comment: Consult an expert, you might have to pay a little fee but, they might be able to tell you exactly what you need for your individual case. I suggest you do not try to apply on your own especially after the rejection your case needs to be air-tight

Comment: @ITguy that's funds parking and is a very bad idea! https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab

Comment: @stanri should i withdraw the amount my parents deposited then ? 
or what should i do ?

Comment: @dexer I don't know enough to answer that question. You probably should get professional advice.